# select result is not complete?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run this query but myfield does not contain the full email address, lastname ,phone and email promotion values? It looks like there is a limit on the length of myField?

sql statement:

```
use adventureworks 
go 

select si.CustomerID, 
'myField' = 
            CASE 
                 When (Select Top 1 FirstName+ ' ' + MiddleName + ' '+ Phone  + ' ' + EmailAddress  +' '+ LastName + ' ' + Phone + ' ' + cast(EmailPromotion as varchar)   From Person.Contact pc Where si.ContactID = pc.contactid ) is not null Then  
            Cast((Select Top 1 FirstName+ ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + Phone  + ' ' +EmailAddress  +' '+ LastName + ' ' + Phone + ' ' + cast(EmailPromotion as varchar) From Person.Contact pc Where si.ContactID = pc.contactid  ) As varchar) 
            Else '' 
            END 

from Sales.Individual si 
where si.CustomerID=11000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `varchar[(n)]`:

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1. . When n is not specified with the
>   CAST function, the default length is 30.

So explicitly specify a suitably long length in your `CAST`, e.g. `varchar(256)`

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258242%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).